# How to replace the certain character in certain position in the string?

Tags: r

I have a question that is how to replace a character which is in a certain place. For example:

```
str <- c("abcdccc","hijklccc","abcuioccc")
#I want to replace character "c" which is in position 3 to "X" how can I do that?
#I know the function gsub and substr, but the only idea I have got so far is 
#use if() to make it. How can I do it quickly?
#ideal result
>str
"abXdccc" "hijklccc" "abXuioccc"
```

Comment: @PKumar thanks, but it will replace all the "c" within the string. I just want to replace "c" in position 3.

Comment: @Sotos it still replace all "c" within the string

Comment: True. Did not notice that

Comment: @thelatemail thank you, your answer works. Please add it to answer. I will take it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you can use a regex lookahead here to get what you are after.

```
str <- c("abcdccc","hijklccc","abcuioccc")
gsub("(^.{2})(?=c)(.*$)", "\\1X\\2", str, perl = T)
```

Or using a positive lookbehind as suggested by thelatemail

```
sub("(?<=^.{2})c", "X", str, perl = TRUE)
```

What this is doing is looking to match the letter `c` which is after any two characters from the start of the string. The `c` is replaced with `X`.

`(?<=` is the start of positive lookbehind

`^.{2}` means any two characters from the start of the string

`)c` is the last part which says it has to be a c after the two characters

---

```
[1] "abXcdccc"   "hijklccc"   "abXcuioccc"
```

If you want to read up more about regex being used ([link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))

---

Additionally a generalised function:

```
switch_letter <- function(x, letter, position, replacement) {
  stopifnot(position > 1)

  pattern <- paste0("(?<=^.{", position - 1, "})", letter)

  sub(pattern, replacement, x, perl = TRUE)

}

switch_letter(str, "c", 3, "X")
```

Comment: Thank you, could you tell me what is "(^.{2})(?=c)(.*$)" means?

Comment: Would just `sub("(?<=^.{2})c", "X", str, perl=TRUE)` cover it? (I might be overlooking something)

Comment: @thelatemail it seems to, my answer is just what i defaulted to didn't really try optimise.

Comment: Your answer is to insert a X into the string but I want to replace it.

Comment: @Codezy let me explain it and you can do anything you want with it then

Comment: @zacdav thank you~ actually sub("(?<=^.{2})c", "X", str, perl=TRUE) this code is working better than thelatemail's. It can use the logical symbol.

Comment: @Codezy No problem, I've added some explanation. It's worth having a read for some basic regex knowledge - its sometimes usefully, not always the best solution however.

Comment: Is it possible to move ^.{2} out of the " " ? I want to make a loop, but i can not be recognise in a quotation mark

Comment: @Codezy what are you trying to do in a loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173539/discussion-between-codezy-and-zacdav).

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit awkward, but you can replace a single character dependent on that single character's value like:

```
ifelse(substr(str,3,3)=="c", `substr<-`(str,3,3,"X"), str)
#[1] "abXdccc"   "hijklccc"  "abXuioccc"
```

If you are happy to overwrite the value, you could do it a bit cleaner:

```
substr(str[substr(str,3,3)=="c"],3,3) <- "X"
str
#[1] "abXdccc"   "hijklccc"  "abXuioccc"
```

Comment: Whoa, @thelatemail, this is quite awkward indeed. But it works fine, even for data frame. Thank you!
Now, what is the rationale in using substr in quotes (`substr<-`)? What does it do, exactly?

Comment: @Douglas - run it separately `\`substr<-\`(str,3,3,"X")` and it should be clearer. It's a shorthand for running `substr(str,3, 3) <- "X"` and returning the result. `substr<-` is a function just like `substr`, but these "replacement" functions need to be quoted when (mis)used like I have here.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `ifelse` with `gsub`, i.e.

```
ifelse(substr(str, 3, 3) == 'c', paste0(substring(str, 1, 2),'X', substring(str, 4)), str)
#[1] "abXdccc"   "hijklccc"  "abXuioccc"
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
str <- c("abcdefg","hijklnm","abcuiowre")
a <- strsplit(str[1], "")[[1]]
a[3] <- "X"
a <- paste(a, collapse = '')
str[1] <- a
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this idea:

```
c2Xon3 <- function(x){sprintf("%s%s%s",substring(x,1,3),gsub("c","X",substring(x,3,3)),substring(x,4,nchar(x)))}
str <- c("abcdccc","hijklccc","abcuioccc")
strNew <- sapply(str,c2Xon3 )
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
str <- c("abcdefg","hijklnm","abcuiowre")

for (i in 1:length(str))
{
  if (substr(str[i],3,3)=='c') {
    substr(str[i], 3, 3) <- "X"
  } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have the same idea as yours. thelatemail have a more simple and direct answer.